# using loops and dictionaries for decoding a morse code program

Tags: python, dictionary, morse-code

I am writing encode and decode functions for morse code. The encode function is working, but the decode function is giving the same output multiple times. Can someone see how i can fix the for loop to only print once. Btw it is printing backwards because I have it printing like that

sample input for decode function

```
....  .  .-..  .-..  ---
```

expected output

```
HELLO
```

output

```
OLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEHOLLEH
```

my code

```
MORSE_CODES={'A':'.-','B':'-...','C':'-.-.',
'D':'-..','E':'.','F':'..-.','G':'--.',
'H':'....','I':'..','J':'.---','K':'-.-',
'L':'.-..','M':'--','N':'-.','O':'---',
'P':'.--.','Q':'--.-','R':'.-.',
'S':'...','T':'-','U':'..-','V':'...-',
'W':'.--','X':'-..-','Y':'-.--','Z':'--..'}


def decode_Morse(my_msg): 
 
  string=" "
  
  for morsecode in my_msg:
    wordsplit=my_msg.split()

    for ch in wordsplit:
      if ch!="  ":
        string=string+ list(MORSE_CODES.keys())[list(MORSE_CODES.values()).index(ch)] 
      else:
        ch=" "
      
  return string

def main()
     my_msg_reverse_Morse_plain=decode_Morse(my_msg_reverse_Morse)
     print("Plaintext of the previous Morse Code:",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about simply this?

```
MORSE_DECODES = {v:k for k,v in MORSE_CODES.items()}
def decode_Morse(my_msg):
    return "".join(MORSE_DECODES[ch] for ch in my_msg.split())
```

Your own code uses one too many loops, try this:

```
def decode_Morse(my_msg): 
 
  string=""
  
  for morsecode in my_msg.split():
      string=string+list(MORSE_CODES.keys())[list(MORSE_CODES.values()).index(morsecode)]
      
  return string
```

If you have multiple words then you must use a different separator for mere letters and words. For example on space for letters, 3 for words, then this will work:

```
def decode_Morse(my_msg): 
  string = ""
  for word in my_msg.split("   "):
      for ch in word.split():
          string=string+list(MORSE_CODES.keys())[list(MORSE_CODES.values()).index(ch)]
      string = string + " "
  return string
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I am not allowed to use extra variables / another dictionary outside of the function. Is there another way to get it output once?

Comment: that worked, but when I have multiple words in a string, it shoves them together so any tips for how to add spaces between words

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to define a reversed dictionary that maps the Morse codes to the characters and then map them to the codes:

```py
# Reversed dictionary: 
my_msg = '....  .  .-..  .-..  --- '
rkey = {v:k for k,v in MORSE_CODES.items()}
answer = "".join(map(lambda x: rkey[x], my_msg.split()))
print(answer)
# HELLO
```

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but I am not allowed to use extra variables / another dictionary outside of the function. Is there another way to get it output once?